# Using select field in owl carousel slide

Tags: owl-carousel

[image]owl carousel plugin returns error when I change select value, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post pictures here so we don't lose them if/when that link goes down. You might want to add a more thorough description of your problem, and consider posting some code. Questions akin to "I have an error, how do I fix it?" tend to get ignored...

Comment: @Conduit, I can't attach images, because I'm newbie here

Comment: My bad - didn't know that was a new user limitation... it's been a while. Got you covered, in any case. Just have to wait for my edit to be approved.

Answer (score 0):

You can off event and all will be work.

```
owl.owlCarousel();
owl.unbind('change');
```

and then you can use select.change(...);

or you can write custom droppdown list without tag "select"

It's work
 for me))